# How can data be plotted in front of axes with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

I have some code to generate [parallel coordinates plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_coordinates).

[image]

It seems to work fine, except for the fact that it is sometimes very difficult to follow the connected lines of one dataset, particularly when there are many datasets plotted and when the dataset lines feature horizontal line segments. One way to make this more clear could be to ensure that dataset lines are plotted *on top* of all axes. How could this be done with matplotlib?

The code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

import matplotlib.pyplot
import pyprel            # pip install pyprel
import shijian           # pip install shijian

def main():

    data = [
        [0.9498061441975048, 0.6049394236952985, 5.168760062095979, 6.571102071810909, 0.3258710500404989],
        [0.6900900610786396, 0.044651963051884014, 5.6222021103273185, 6.413258445862534, 0.3989822610565017],
        [0.40245822087321015, 0.9000644399147708, 5.698656759965443, 5.706219545980181, 1.2501169295120753],
        [0.007788240630026866, 1.6630324065241182, 5.326062675832998, 6.198416367191167, 1.3785261503382713],
        [1.2329258057665577, 1.3760208006135484, 5.40272344446576, 5.697339583623006, 1.6475096314400532],
        [1.3736286937326467, 1.618862515954041, 5.9745190659395355, 5.252136196112335, 0.36162007500593485]
    ]

    save_parallel_coordinates_matplotlib(
        data,
        filename = "parallel_coordinates_1.png"
    )

def save_parallel_coordinates_matplotlib(
    datasets,
    styles              = None,
    title               = None,
    label_x             = "",
    label_y             = "",
    labels_ticks_x_axis = None, # under consideration
    filename            = None,
    directory           = ".",
    overwrite           = True,
    LaTeX               = False
    ):

    matplotlib.pyplot.ioff()
    if LaTeX is True:
        matplotlib.pyplot.rc("text", usetex = True)
        matplotlib.pyplot.rc("font", family = "serif")
    if filename is None:
        filename = shijian.propose_filename(
            filename  = title.replace(" ", "_") + ".png",
            overwrite = overwrite
        )
    else:
        filename = shijian.propose_filename(
            filename  = filename,
            overwrite = overwrite
        )

    dimensions = len(datasets[0])
    if labels_ticks_x_axis is None:
        labels_ticks_x_axis = range(dimensions)
    figure, axes        = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots(
        1,
        dimensions - 1,
        sharey  = False,
        figsize = (14, 14)
    )

    # If no list of line styles is set, create a list of colors for lines.
    if styles is None:
        colors = pyprel.access_palette(
            name = "palette21",
            minimum_number_of_colors_needed = len(datasets)
        )
        styles = colors

    # Calculate limits of data for each feature.
    range_minimum_maximum = list()
    for dataset in zip(*datasets):
        minimum_value = min(dataset)
        maximum_value = max(dataset)
        if minimum_value == maximum_value:
            minimum_value -= 0.5
            maximum_value = minimum_value + 1.
        range_of_values = float(maximum_value - minimum_value)
        range_minimum_maximum.append((
            minimum_value,
            maximum_value,
            range_of_values
        ))

    # Normalize datasets.
    datasets_normalized = list()
    for dataset in datasets:
        dataset_normalized = [
            (value - range_minimum_maximum[dimension][0]) /
            range_minimum_maximum[dimension][2]
            for dimension, value in enumerate(dataset)
        ]
        datasets_normalized.append(dataset_normalized)
    datasets = datasets_normalized

    # Plot datasets on all subplots.
    for index_axis, axis in enumerate(axes):
        for index_dataset, dataset in enumerate(datasets):
            axis.plot(labels_ticks_x_axis, dataset, styles[index_dataset])
        axis.set_xlim([
            labels_ticks_x_axis[index_axis],
            labels_ticks_x_axis[index_axis + 1]
        ])

    # Set all y-axis ticks except last.
    for dimension, (axes_most, label_tick_x_axis) in enumerate(zip(axes, labels_ticks_x_axis[:-1])):
        axes_most.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator([label_tick_x_axis]))
        number_of_ticks    = len(axes_most.get_yticklabels())
        labels_ticks       = list()
        step_ticks         = range_minimum_maximum[dimension][2] / (number_of_ticks - 1)
        value_minimum_tick = range_minimum_maximum[dimension][0]
        labels_ticks = [
            "{value:4.2f}".format(
                value = (value_minimum_tick + index_tick * step_ticks)
            ) for index_tick in xrange(number_of_ticks)
        ]
        axes_most.set_yticklabels(labels_ticks)

    # Set all last y-axis ticks to the right of the plot.
    axes_last = matplotlib.pyplot.twinx(axes[-1])
    dimension += 1
    axes_last.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator([
        labels_ticks_x_axis[-2], labels_ticks_x_axis[-1]
    ]))
    number_of_ticks    = len(axes_last.get_yticklabels())
    step_ticks         = range_minimum_maximum[dimension][2] / (number_of_ticks - 1)
    value_minimum_tick = range_minimum_maximum[dimension][0]
    labels_ticks = [
        "{value:4.2f}".format(
            value = (value_minimum_tick + index_tick * step_ticks)
        ) for index_tick in xrange(number_of_ticks)
    ]
    axes_last.set_yticklabels(labels_ticks)

    # Stack subplots.
    matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust(wspace = 0)

    if title is not None:
        figure.suptitle(title, fontsize = 20)
    matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel(label_x)
    matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel(label_y)
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
    matplotlib.pyplot.savefig(
        directory + "/" + filename,
        bbox_inches        = "tight",
        dpi                = 700
    )
    matplotlib.pyplot.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the zorder?

Comment: @tom Hey, thanks for the suggestion. I had not heard of this `zorder` feature before and it looks promising. Would you happen to know how it could be applied to the axes (at least in the way I'm using them in my code)?